# Python Equivalent of Java's 'Keystore'?

Tags: python, cryptography

Is there a standard mechanism for storing/retrieving cryptographic keys and certificates in the Python platform: equivalent to the 'keystore(/truststore)' in the Java Platform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python standard library doesn't contain any manual encryption (only hashing). There is no real *standard* mechanism.

If you're using the [ssl module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl-certificates) then you can store client certificates (for authentication) and CA certificates (for chain validation) in a text which can be loaded into the SSLContext.

Comment: Thanks - my program has 'import Crypto' - maybe I pip installed another library at some point (pyCrypto?) - anyway I'm  storing passwords directly in code (rather than in a 'store') - was just trying to tidy up using a 'master' password - but didn't want re-invent the wheel

Comment: Revised answer (according to the general question). AFAIK, pyCrypto doesn't have something similar to a keystore.

Answer (score 2):

PKCS12 Is the common standard. Pythons "from OpenSSL import crypto" handles this common standard.  As certificates and RSA keys are important to keep secured its strongly recommended to use encrypted stores with pass-phrases to keep all you certs and keys safe from prying eyes.